# Sed for loop GNU Linux on Synology NAS

Tags: bash, sed, synology

I am working on a short script to search a large number of folders on a NAS for this odd character `` and delete the character. I am on a Synology NAS running Linux. This is what I have so far.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$(find "/volume1/PLNAS/" -depth -type d -name '**')";
do
  echo "$file";
  mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed s/// )";
done
```

Current problem is that the Kernel does not appear to be passing each MV command separately. I get a long error message that appears to list every file in one command, truncated error message below. There are spaces in my file path and that it why I have tried to quote every variable.

```
mv: failed to access '/volume1/PLNAS/... UT Thickness Review ': File name too long
```

Comment: `find "/volume1/PLNAS/" -depth -type d -name '**' -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1//}"' -- {} \;`

Comment: @jhnc I am not sure which part you're asking to clarify. `--` becomes $0 in the `bash -c` and the filename is `$1`

Comment: @jhnc ah, now I see what you're saying and that's a good thing to look out for. I am pretty sure that's not required here as what `find` would actually pass is `./-h`, which is ok.

Comment: @jordanm Oops. you're right. Can't happen. (`/volume1/PLNAS/.../-h` unless you use `-execdir`)

Comment: Apparently the Unicode is U+F028.

If you've got Python installed, you could do CHARS=$(python2 -c 'print u"\uF028".encode("utf8")');
sed 's/['"$CHARS"']//g'

Answer (score 0):

Several issues. The most important is probably that `for file in "$(find...)"` iterates only once with `file` set to the full result of your search. This is what the double quotes are for: prevent word splitting.

But `for file in $(find...)` is not safe: if some file names contain spaces they will be split...

Assuming the character is unicode `0xf028` (  ) try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  new_file="${file//$'\uf028'}"
  printf 'mv %s %s\n' "$file" "$new_file"
#  mv "$file" "$new_file"
done < <(find "/volume1/PLNAS/" -depth -type d -name $'*\uf028*' -print0)
```

Uncomment the `mv` line if things look correct.

As your file names are unusual we use the `-d ''` read separator and the `print0` find option. This will use the NUL character (ASCII code zero) as separator between the file names instead of the default newline characters. The NUL character is the only one that you cannot find in a full file name.

We also use the bash `$'...'` expansion to represent the unwanted character by its unicode hexadecimal code, it is safer than copy-pasting the glyph. The new name is computed with the bash pattern substitution (`${var//}`).

Note: do not use `echo` with unusual strings, especially without quoting the strings (e.g. your `echo $file | ...`). Prefer `printf` or quoted here strings (`sed ... <<< "$file"`).